# textFieldShouldReturn: called for some text fields within a table cell but not for others

Tags: ios

I have some cells in a static table, and the cells contain UITextFields.

The controller for the table view and cells derives from UITextFieldDelegate and implements
textFieldShouldReturn:

This is being called for two cells, but its not being called for another cell. I have double and triple and quadruple checked that all the connections between IB and the code are correct, and I've compared the cells/text fields that do work with cell containing the text fields for which textFieldShouldReturn: isn't being called - and there is no difference, they and the connections etc. are all identical. 
Except for one difference - the cells which contain a UITextField for which textFieldShouldReturn each contain just one UITextField, however the other cell contains 3 instances of UITextField.

However I can't see why this would result in textFieldShouldReturn: not being called?

Any suggestion as to why textFieldShouldReturn: is being called for two of my table cells but not the other one?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the delegate for all the UITextFields is set properly.